# Scroll action cannot currently be transcribed by Appium Recorder

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, ios-ui-automation, appium

I want to use the appium recorder to record the action of scrolling. When I click the button of 'Scroll To', it really scrolls to the correct location. But it doesn't transcribe to code.
This error is 'Action cannot currently be transcribed by Appium Recorder'.I don't know what's the problem with it. Anyone knows?

The testing environment is:

mac OSX 10.9.3

Appium 1.0.0

iPhone Simulator 7.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use 'Swipe' instead of scroll to. Click on Swipe button , select the start and end points by clicking on the image of screen on Inspector and click on perform . I hope this action gets recorded.